# Period of decimal for $1/n$, odd part of $n+1$, and primes.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Let $n$ be a nature number is coprime to $10$,such that the period of the decimal expansion of $1/n$ is a divisor of $n-1$, and let $c$ be the "cycle length of $n$" (defined below). If $n-1=2^xc$ or $n+1=2^xc$ for some $x\in\Bbb{N}^{>0}$, then $n$ is prime.

For example, using $n=41$:

The period of $1/41=0.0243902439\dots$ is $5$ and $5$ is a divisor of $41-1$, the "cycle length of $41$" is $10$, $(41-1)/10 = 4 = 2^2$, so $41$ is prime.

Is there any counterexample to this?

To define the "cycle length of $n$" (using $n=73$ as an example):

```
Step 1 : 73 +  1 =  74. Get the odd part of  74, which is 37    
Step 2 : 73 + 37 = 110. Get the odd part of 110, which is 55
Step 3 : 73 + 55 = 128. Get the odd part of 128, which is  1
```

Continuing this operation (with $73 + 1$) repeats the same steps as above. There are $3$ steps in the cycle, so the cycle length of $73$ is $c=3$.

Comment: What is "the period of $1/n$"? Also, you wrote $41-1=4$.

Comment: 1/41 = 0.0243902439... the period of the decimal expansion of 1/n

Comment: I think this is always a divisor of $n-1$.

Comment: That's (41-1)/10 = 4

Comment: Could you rephrase "If the "cycle length of n" divides n−1 or n+1=2x for some x>0, then n is prime." I'm a bit confused as to where to put the parentheses in this sentence (what does that "or" conjoin?).

Comment: That's divides ($n−1$ or $n+1)$

Comment: Then what is that equals sign for? Did you mean "$\frac{n-1}c=2^x$ or $\frac{n+1}c=2^x$, where $x>0$ and $c$ is the cycle length of $n$"? Note that "$a$ divides $b$" is not a number, but a predicate that means the same as "$a$ is a divisor of $b$". I think you are trying to say "$b$ divided by $a$", which is a number.

Comment: What's wrong with this? $15$ is not a prime, the period of $1/15$ is $1$, which divides $15-1 = 14$. The cycle length of $15$ is also $1$, so the cycle length divides $15+1 = 16 = 2^4$.

Comment: @J.J. Generalizing your result, this procedure labels every $2^n-1$ as prime, which is certainly not true. (Note: $2^n-1$ is relatively prime to $10$ for $n>1$.)

Comment: That's n should be relatively prime to 10

Comment: @Mario Carneiro The periodicity condition might still break. For example $1/63$ has period $6$, which does not divide $62$, so that's not the case.

Comment: miket, if you have more conditions, you should edit them into the body of the question, so folks don't have to trawl through the comments to find them.

Comment: @J.J. Doesn't Euler have a theorem that says that $1/n$ has a period dividing $n-1$? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)

Comment: @Andreas Caranti,  the "cycle length of $33$" is $5$

Comment: @Mario Carneiro I think that holds only for prime $n$.

Comment: @miket, I have a feeling you changed your question, though.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson,thanks for your edit.

Comment: If there is such a number $n$ which is not prime, since $10^{n-1}\equiv 1 \pmod n,n$ should be a seudoprime to base 10. The first $1000$ of these numbers are list in http://oeis.org/A005939 ,from $9,33,$ to $17931453,$ but there is no such number among them.

Comment: Also posted, with no link here, to MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/131900/period-of-decimal-for-1-n-odd-part-of-n1-and-primes

Comment: The period of $n$ is a divisor of $\varphi(n)$, where $\varphi$ denotes the Euler totient function. This follows from Euler's theorem, which tells us that
$10^{\varphi(n)}\equiv1\ (\operatorname{mod}\ n)$, or in other words, that $$n\mid10^{\varphi(n)}-1.$$ 
It follows that
$$10^{\varphi(n)}\cdot\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n}\in\mathbb{Z},$$
which shows that the period of $n$ divides $\varphi(n)$.

Comment: Dear User84559 ,more see http://oeis.org/A225890

Comment: @Barry Cipra, Counterexample to this question is http://oeis.org/A225890, except a(1) all are semiprimes,how about the next counterexample?