# Odd part of $n-1$ and primes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, recursion

Using $n=11$ as an example:

```
Step 1 : 11 - 1 =  10. Get the odd part of  10, which is 5    
Step 2 : 11 - 5 =   6. Get the odd part of   6, which is 3
Step 3 : 11 - 3 =   8. Get the odd part of   8, which is 1
```

Continuing this operation (with $11-1$) repeats the same steps as above. There are three consecutive odd numbers $1,3,5$  from $1$ to $(n-1)/2$ in the cycle, so the number $11$ has a "full counter cycle".

Is there any counterexample that a number has a "full counter cycle" but isn't prime?

Comment: It must be late: I cannot understand what's the question, what's a full (counter or not) cycle, what does "continuing this operation (with 11-1)" (what, didn't we do that above already?), etc. If I mimic what you did above with $\,15\,$ I also get $\,1,3,5,7\,$...is this good?

Comment: $15-1=14 \ od(14)=7 \ 15-7=8 \ od(8)=1 \  15(1,7)$

Comment: Yes...so? Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Counter means $-1$,there's another positive way $+1$

Comment: ?!? Ok, this doesn't seem to be for me: I've no idea what's going on here.

Comment: I Check the sequence $7, 11, 13, 19, 23, 29, 37, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 79, 83, 101, 103$ at OEIS just now,this is already in the OEIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n$ be a positive integer, and define the sequence $(c_i)_{i\geq0}$ inductively by 
$$c_0=n-1,\qquad c_{i+1}=\operatorname{odd}(n-c_i).$$
I understand your question to be:

> Is there a composite $n$ such that every odd number less that $\frac{n-1}{2}$ occurs in the sequence $(c_i)_{i\geq0}$?

Note that $\gcd(n,c_0)=1$, and that 
$$\gcd(n,c_{i+1})=\gcd(n,\operatorname{odd}(n-c_i))\mid\gcd(n,n-c_i)=\gcd(n,c_i).$$
Hence $\gcd(n,c_i)=1$ for all $i\geq0$. Hence no divisor of $n$ other than $1$ occurs in the sequence $(c_i)_{i\geq0}$. So no counterexample exists with $n$ composite and odd.

A counterexample with $n$ composite and even is easy; take $n=4$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $c_0=1$ instead? Also $n$ even isn't very interesting, since we have $c_0=1, c_1=n-1, c_2=1, \ldots$, so actually the only composite $n$ which work are $4$ and $6$.

Comment: @User84559 Thanks for your great proof!Then how about the odd part of $n+1$ and primes?See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402663/period-of-decimal-for-1-n-odd-part-of-n1-and-primes

Comment: Actually ignore that; you get $c_1=1$ anyway, so it does not matter.